# How to display custom confirmation message based on current form response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am working on one google form. Need to display confirmation message based on current form input data. I have tried the same. 
Issue Facing:

1) When i tried first time in the form it is showing confirmation message based on current form input data.
2) When i tried second time in the form it is again showing confirmation message based on first form input instead of current form input.
3) When i tried third time it is showing confirmation message based on second form input instead of current form input.

Since i am new to this kindly let me know whether it is possible in google form. If not please provide alternative options to achieve this as i need.

Comment: It's well documented that this can't be done.

Comment: You can do it through forwarding to a dynamically created WebApp, but you can show first the code you tried so far that lead to the behavior your mentioned?